# Differentiate PDE with respect to $f(x)^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I need to minimize a (very simple) functional using variational calculus:

$F (x,\,f (x),f'(x)) = 5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)$

Plugging that into the Euler-Lagrange equation gives

$\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\left(5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)\right)
- \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial f'}\left(5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)\right) = 0$

For the second term I find

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial f'}\left(5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)\right) = 3x^2 + 6x + 9$

For the first term I would intutitively say

$\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\left(5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)\right) = 5$

because $f$ ist not squared (only the result of $f$ is), but plugging that into Wolframalpha gives

$\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\left(5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)\right) = 0$

Is this correct and how can I get there?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\left(5f(x)^2 + (x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x)\,f'(x)\right) = 10f(x)$, just consider $f(x)$ as a variable and do $\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}$ like a normal derivative.

Comment: Ok, it's that easy.. Thanks a lot!